# How to ensure, that column names are equal in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, constants

I am currently working on a laravel php project. In this case, a table containing countries should be created. There are three fields within the table: a short country code column called `country_code` and the name of the country in german and english language in the columns `country_name_de` and `country_code_en`.
This results in the following model class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Country
 * @package App\Models
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
final class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'countries';

    protected $primaryKey = 'country_code';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fillable = [
        'country_code',
        'country_name_de',
        'country_name_en',
    ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    public static function getCountryCodeColumnName(): string
    {
        return 'country_code';
    }

    public static function getGermanCountryNameColumnName(): string
    {
        return 'country_name_de';
    }

    public static function getEnglishCountryNameColumnName(): string
    {
        return 'country_name_en';
    }

    public static function getTableName(): string
    {
        return 'countries';
    }


}
```

Further, there is a seeder to write the needed values into the database. The seeder of course needs the column names to insert data. Currently I am using this method within the seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    // Load CSV-file country_codes.csv
    if (($handle = fopen(storage_path('app/country_codes.csv'), 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
            $country = array(
                Country::getCountryCodeColumnName()         => $data[0],
                Country::getGermanCountryNameColumnName()   => $data[1],
            Country::getEnglishCountryNameColumnName()  => $data[2],
            );
            Country::create($country);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Is it a good style to use 'constants'/getters to ensure, that there is no typo in any class referencing a specific column of the table? And is it possible to use this style also for the migrations or are there any problems with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration should not be dependent on any `Model` reference.

Actually if you have `$fillable` set in your model, using getters would not be needed, because Eloquent will do that for you.
To ensure correctness, you can verify that your tables has required columns by:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('countries'); 
// check if $columns have all your required column
```

In a different approach, you can do this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
  $country = new Country();
  $country->setCountryCode = $data[0];
  $country->setCountryNameDe = $data[0];
  $country->setCountryNameEn = $data[1];
  $country->save();
}
```

By this you don't need those boilerplate method in your model, eloquent will populate respective fields of your model's table.

Comment: Okay, how do I define setCountyCode? Or how can I prevent the ‚used magic method‘ warning of my IDE Phpstorm?

Comment: Yes that is a problem, IDE mainly complains as it can not find the definition of the method. I am using [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) for long time, it basically generates all the code snippets to satisfy the IDE. You can give it a try.

Comment: okay. I installed it and typed `php artisan ide-helper:generate`, but still it does not notice `setCountryCode` and the others. Why is that?

Comment: Did you try "File > Invalidating Cache & Restart" in the PHPStorm?

Comment: I forgot to start the local database server, which is quite important! So, if it helps anybody: Start the used database server, run `php artisan migrate` and optionally `php artisan db:seed` and then run `php artisan ide-helper:models`